# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) clion

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, compiler-errors, clion

I was doing the PlusMinus question of hackerrank so it was coming out wrong. To check for the mistake I ran it in Clion but the error showed up. Can someone please tell me why this happened and what should I do so that this error does not show up again ?

**Error**

```
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/Clion.dir/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Clion.dir/plus_minus.cpp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void plusMinus(vector<int> arr) {
    float i,pos,neg,zero;
    //n=arr.size();
    for(i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        if(arr.at(i)<0)
            neg++;
        else if(arr.at(i)>0)
            pos++;
        else if(arr.at(i)==0)
            zero++;
    }
    pos=pos/arr.size();
    neg=neg/arr.size();
    zero=zero/arr.size();
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(6)<<pos<<"\n"<<neg<<"\n"<<zero;
    return ;

}

int main()
{
    int n,temp;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> arr;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>temp;
        arr.push_back(temp);
    }
    plusMinus(arr);
}
```

Comment: So you have only shown one file in this post, but if you look at the output from the linker `CMakeFiles/Clion.dir/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Clion.dir/plus_minus.cpp.o` you are clearly linking two files. Presumably both these files have a `main` function and so you get a duplicate symbol error. The answer is to only compile and link one program at a time.

Comment: Yes. This project file has in total 2 files but I clicked on run button of Clion. How will I get to know if files are compiling together or not and how to compile the code individually ?

Comment: I don't know CLion but if it's anything like other tools you need two separate projects for two separate programs.